# CodeMirror: allow VimFx

Tags: firefox, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, codemirror

VimFx is a Firefox extension that allow you to click on a link or on a text field with `f`, and to enter visual mode on plain text with `v`.

To jump to a CodeMirror editor one would expect to use `f` rather than `v`, because a CodeMirror editor is an editable text zone.

`f` is indeed working perfectly to edit [CodeMirror's demo](http://codemirror.net/).

However, **I cannot use `f` on Compiler-Explorer UI ([live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)).**

The problem can probably be fixed by changing the HTML code that embed CodeMirror.

*Note that `v` is working in this case, but does not satisfy me as I would like to enable CodeMirror's vim key bindings.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in VimFx as of [commit 62f2f030](https://github.com/akhodakivskiy/VimFx/commit/62f2f030b3a9ddec4cd087c8b9ec41875cef6626), and is available in version 0.19.0.